# NumberFormatException with Simple Encryption

Tags: java, numberformatexception

```
package codeCracker;

public class CodeCracker {
    private String encrypt;
    private int encry;

    public CodeCracker(String encryptmelong) {
        encrypt = encryptmelong;
    }

    public String idolnum() {
        String in;
        in = encrypt;
        in = in.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
        encry = Integer.valueOf(in);
        encrypt = encrypt.replace(in, "");
        // System.out.println(encry);
        return in;
    }

    public String encrypt() {
        // encrypt+=encry;

        String encrypted = "";
        String charen = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length(); i++) {
            charen += encrypt.charAt(i);
            // System.out.println(charen.charAt(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < charen.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(encry);
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(idolnum());
            System.out.println("" + temp + " " + (int) encrypt.charAt(i));
            temp = (int) encrypt.charAt(i) + temp;
            encrypted = encrypted + (char) temp;
            // System.out.println(encrypted.charAt(i));
        }
        return encrypted;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return encrypt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CodeCracker code = new CodeCracker("5 encryptme");
        System.out.println(code);
    }

}
```

I have a question about encryption. This program is supposed to receive a string and a number and increase each char by this number. This is not working. It receives the number properly but does not add the chars correctly. I am also receiving the error of an exception in the thread "main": for input string: ""

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at
    Java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at 
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504) at 
    java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582) at 
    codeCracker.CodeCracker.idolnum(CodeCracker.java:15) at 
    codeCracker.CodeCracker.encrypt(CodeCracker.java:34) at 
    codeCracker.CodeCracker.toString(CodeCracker.java:44) at 
    java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854) at 
    java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821) at 
    codeCracker.CodeCracker.main(CodeCracker.java:50)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace exception text and indicate for us which line throws it.

Comment: Just a guess here, but it appears that in the second for loop, when you run `System.out.println(entry);` the first time, you don't have `encry` set to anything, which may cause your problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
 at codeCracker.CodeCracker.idolnum(CodeCracker.java:15)
 at codeCracker.CodeCracker.encrypt(CodeCracker.java:34)
 at codeCracker.CodeCracker.toString(CodeCracker.java:44)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
 at codeCracker.CodeCracker.main(CodeCracker.java:50)

Comment: The error message is telling you that you're trying to parse `""` as an Integer at line 15 of your class: `encry = Integer.valueOf(in);`. Consider stepping through your code with a debugger to find out why. It looks like you're trying to get the encry number multiple times which doesn't make sense -- you only want to extract it and save it once.

Comment: I did this. It is still interpreting the encry value as 0. that is the value that was assigned idolnum();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < charen.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(encry);
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(idolnum());
        System.out.println("" + temp + " " + (int) encrypt.charAt(i));
        temp = (int) encrypt.charAt(i) + temp;
        encrypted = encrypted + (char) temp;
        // System.out.println(encrypted.charAt(i));
    }
```

You're calling `idolnum()` multiple times within the for loop, including after you've extracted the number String from the original String, and so when you do this a second time, you get the `NumberFormatException` for trying to parse "". Instead of doing this, call `diolnum()` once and only once, and before the for loop. Then use the encry int whenever the encryption int is needed.

Note that if this were my project, I'd organize it differently. I'd only pass the encryption int to the class, and then allow it to encrypt and decrypt whatever Strings are passed into it. For example:

```
public class MyCodeCracker {
    private int encry;

    public MyCodeCracker(int encry) {
        this.encry = encry;
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) {
        // use encry to do encrytion
        return "";  // return encrypted text
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
        // use encry to translate encryptedText to text
        return ""; // return text
    }

    public int getEncry() {
        return encry;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // here get user input
        // extract out the encryption int
        // create MyCodeCracker with the int
        // and then encrypt and decrypt text as needed
    }

}
```

Comment: .......... LOL so I never initialized code.idolnum(); so the idolnum method never ran

Comment: @GamerGuy: no! It ran, but ran too many times. Please re-read my answer, and please run your code with a debugger to see.

Comment: Yeah, i did. I changed that too. Thanks for that. I also never ran it so it never changed the value of encry

Comment: @GamerGuy: yes it in fact does change the encry result. Question, is your input always a number followed by a phrase? If so, I would try to simplify this greatly.

Comment: @GamerGuy: you're welcome. Please note edits to answer. I would have the class only hold the int as field, and then allow it to encrypt or decrypt whatever Strings are passed into its encrypt and decrypt methods.